# Passing variables between jQuery and other javascript global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble letting functions I defined in jquery to read javascript values i defined elsewhere.
for example I have a function defined within my jquery

```
var parentImg = ''; //global variable.

$(document).change(function() {
  if ($("#parentImage option:selected").val())
    parentImg = $("#parentImage option:selected").val();
    alert(parentImg);
});

$(function(){
    $('#swfuploadcontrol').swfupload({
        upload_url: "upload-file.php?page=<?php echo $htmlFile; ?>&parentImg=" + parentImg});})
```

but I can't let it read a global variable I defined at top ""parentImg"". It seems like everything defined within jquery lives in its own space and doesn't interact with the outside world..

any idea of how i can pass these values back and forth btw jquery and the rest of the code?

How can I pass "parentImg" variable value long with "upload_url" variable..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting a variable available to both just fine...jQuery doesn't in any way have it's own variable, it's all JavaScript.  The problem is the *order* in which your code is firing, are the `document.ready` handler bound in the right order?

Right now you're binding to the `change` event on `document` (presumably to capture bubbling `change` events?...this could be right on the element), but that'll run *after* your `.swfupload()` call (which runs on `document.ready`).